# bind selector options to variable

Tags: angularjs

I have some code that's a bool 'public'.  I want to create a select that allows the user to change this.  Here's how I've done it:

```
<select class="prompter-public-textfield" ng-model=selectedItem.public
                                          value={{selectedItem.public}}>
    <option>Public</option>
    <option>Non-public</option>
</select>
```

The issue is 'public' is 0 and 1, but this doesn't make much sense to the user.  Is there any elegant way to display 'Public' and 'Non-public' in the selector, but bind this to 0 and 1 in my object?  (I'm trying not to create another variable or use a onchange to modify).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ts6YCuClkFTU1Ibmcb6r?p=preview

```
selectedItem : {{selectedItem}}<br/>
   <select class="prompter-public-textfield" ng-model="selectedItem.public">
    <option value="0">Public</option>
    <option value="1">Non-public</option>
</select>
```